# Bengali text change in pdf from source text in xelatex

Tags: fonts, xetex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem,anyfontsize}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0cm,top=0.7cm,bottom=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
%\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Biolinum O}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{NikoshLightBAN}
\begin{document}
\centering
\multido{}{2}
{{\fontsize{71}{85.2} \selectfont \selectlanguage{english} AL DHAFRA \selectlanguage{bengali} ব্রান্ডের প্যাকেটজাত \selectlanguage{english} DABBAS \selectlanguage{bengali} খেজুর এবং মধু পাওয়া যায়\\}{\fontsize{52}{62.4}\selectfont মোবাঃ \selectlanguage{english}01515611989\\ \selectlanguage{bengali} রুম -\selectlanguage{english} 1406, \selectlanguage{english}Ex-1, \selectlanguage{bengali}শহীদুল্লাহ হল\\}\vspace{1.4cm}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

output

[image]

Comment: I can't read the script so it is hard  to comment but for at least this character before 1406, firefox renders it looking more like your output than you show in your source view   (with a filled loop in the middle)    `ম -\selectlanguage{english} 1406`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  see ` ু` of `রুম` instead of `ম`